# Does Parse.com support message queue?

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, message-queue, messaging

I am using `Parse.com` in order to message to my clients but i found `Parse.com` does not buffer messages and if my clients been offline after they become online they just receive the last message

`How i send messages:`

```
        ParseQuery query = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
        query.whereEqualTo("national_id", "****");
        ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
        push.setQuery(query);
        push.clearExpiration();
        push.setMessage("new message");
        push.sendInBackground();
```

what is the problem and how can i solve this issue?

should i change something in parse settings?

thanks in advance,